# @at-root a#{&} results in error

Tags: css, ruby, windows, sass, compass

When I try to use @at-root and Interpolation I'm getting an error... but I'm not sure why... I'm even just using an out-of-the-book example for testing and I still get an error:

```css
.button {
  @at-root a#{&} {
   color: green;
  }
}
```

Error sass/Site.scss (Line 28 of sass/partials/_site-title.scss: Invalid CSS
 after "  @at-root a#{": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "&} {")

The functionality should be there, I'm using Sass 3.4.22 combined with Compass 1.0.3 so I'm thinking its an dev enviroment issue perhaps? I'm use to working on a Mac, but I'm using a Windows 7 computer with ruby 2.2.5p319 (i386 version).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do interpolation like this.

Rename the file to have a `.scss.erb` extension and then do the interpolation with ERB:

```
.button {
  @at-root a<%= "my_string_inserted_with_ruby" %> {
   color: green;
  }
}
```

But I'm unclear ... what is the `&` you're trying to insert, and why are you doing it with interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer but to help with the problem, if I compile your code

`.button {
    @at-root a#{&} {
        color: green;
    }
}`

It compiles to this as expected

`a.button {
    color: green;
}`

So it definitely sounds like a dev environment issues. Sorry I can't help more. I am on a windows machine using atom, with node-sass & sass-autocompile.